# Python - Combining excels after scraping

Tags: python, excel, csv, web-scraping

I followed another persons code to scrape basketball player data for a player for a year, I've automated it so that I can scrape for X player for Y years, but it outputs an excel per year. Is there anyway to scrape it all and have it all in the one excel/csv at the end?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
from random import randint
from datetime import date
import numpy as np

poop = []
# NBA season and player we will be analyzing. Basketball-reference's html code is weird so inputs are in place to extract
year = input("Year End Season: ")
initial = input("Initial of Last Name: ")
last_name = input("First 5 letters of last name: ")
first_name = input("First 2 letters of first name (and 01 at the end unless multiple players with that name): ")
Number_pages = int(input("How many years to scrape? "))

years = range(Number_pages)

for adds in years:
    # URL page we will scraping with inputs from above
    url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/" + str(initial) + "/" + str(last_name) + str(first_name) + "/gamelog/" + str(int(year) + int(adds))

    # this is the HTML from the given URL
    html = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")

    sleep(randint(2,10))

    print(soup.div.h1.text.strip())

    # use findALL() to get the column headers
    container = soup.find('div', class_='table_outer_container')
    container.findAll('tr', limit=2)
    # use getText()to extract the text we need into a list
    headers = [th.getText() for th in container.findAll('tr', limit=2)[0].findAll('th')]

    # exclude the first column as we will not need the ranking order from Basketball Reference for the analysis
    headers = headers[1:]
    headers

    # avoid the first header row
    rows = container.findAll('tr')[1:]
    player_stats = [[td.getText() for td in rows[i].findAll('td')]
                for i in range(len(rows))]

    stats = pd.DataFrame(player_stats, columns = headers)
    stats.head(10)
    poop.append(stats)

    stats.to_csv(soup.div.h1.text.strip() + '.csv')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you already have what you need in the `poop` list;

```
# ... your imports ...

poop = []

# ... your logic ...

for adds in years:

     # ... your logic ...

    stats = pd.DataFrame(player_stats, columns = headers)
    stats.head(10)

    # here, you add each data-frames to the 'poop' list.
    poop.append(stats)

# now, concatenate all the data-frames into one
all_stats = pandas.concat(poop)
```

Comment: Legend this worked exactly as I wanted. 
Sorry about the 'poop' just me mindlessly typing

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate your process in a defined method with a return object and then build a list of data frames via a list or dict comprehension:

**Method**

```
def bball_scrape(adds):
    # URL page we will scraping with inputs from above
    url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/{1}/{2}{3}/gamelog/{4}" 
    url = url.format(str(initial), str(last_name), str(first_name), 
                     str(int(year) + int(adds)))

    # this is the HTML from the given URL
    html = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")

    sleep(randint(2,10))

    print(soup.div.h1.text.strip())

    # use findALL() to get the column headers
    container = soup.find('div', class_='table_outer_container')
    container.findAll('tr', limit=2)
    # use getText()to extract the text we need into a list
    headers = [th.getText() for th in container.findAll('tr', limit=2)[0].findAll('th')]

    # exclude the first column...
    headers = headers[1:]

    # avoid the first header row
    rows = container.findAll('tr')[1:]
    player_stats = [[td.getText() for td in rows[i].findAll('td')]
                     for i in range(len(rows))]

    stats = pd.DataFrame(player_stats, columns = headers)
    stats.to_csv(soup.div.h1.text.strip() + '.csv')

    return stats
```

**Data Frame**

```
df_list = [bball_scrape(adds) for adds in years]
# df_dict = {add:bball_scrape(adds) for adds in years}

final_df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use pandas here to parse the table? Can also simplify some of the inputs too:

```
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
from random import randint


poop = []
# NBA season and player we will be analyzing. Basketball-reference's html code is weird so inputs are in place to extract
year = input("Year End Season: ")
last_name = input("Enter last name: ")

initial = last_name[0]
last_name = last_name[0:5]

first_name = input("Enter first name: ")
first_name = first_name[0:2] + '01'

Number_pages = int(input("How many years to scrape? "))

years = range(Number_pages)

for adds in years:
    # URL page we will scraping with inputs from above
    url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/" + str(initial) + "/" + str(last_name) + str(first_name) + "/gamelog/" + str(int(year) + int(adds))
    stats=pd.read_html(url)[-1]
    poop.append(stats)
    sleep(randint(2,10))
    
all_stats = pd.concat(poop, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```